# How to set Windows Media Player to show frame at specific position

Tags: delphi, windows-media-player

I have created a windows media player ActiveX control.
(see: [Windows Media Player in Delphi](https://chapmanworld.com/windows-media-player-in-delphi/) for further reference).

Everything works fine. here is sample from my code:

```
uses ..., WMPLib_TLB;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MP := TWindowsMediaPlayer.Create(Self);
  MP.Parent := Panel1;
  MP.Align := alClient;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MP.controls.stop;
  MP.URL := 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
  MP.controls.pause;
  MP.controls.currentPosition := 2; // 2 seconds 
end;
```

I want to open a video file/url and show the video frame at a position of X seconds.

However the above code does not stop/pause the video at 2 second and the video simply plays until the end.

How can I pause the frame at position X?

**EDIT:** just to be clear, I want to get a "preview" effect, so when I load the video for the **first time** the media player will show some (first) frame instead of a black screen. then the user can press play to watch the video.

Comment: How about unticking the "auto start" checkbox in the control configuration, just as the article illustrates?

Comment: Pause after setting CurrentPosition, not before. (I don't think the link to the media player post was necessary, BTW. Anybody who can answer this question will know already what TMediaPlayer is and how to use it. It certainly wasn't necessary to SHOUT TO INDICATE THE LINK IS THERE, because the underline and color already indicate that there's a link.)

Comment: or when state changes to be wmppsPlaying. If loading is asynchronous, playing may begin well after the click handler returns.

Comment: @AmigoJack, That does not make any difference. the `MP.controls.isAvailable['currentPosition']` at that point returns false.

Comment: @KenWhite, Pause before or After has no effect. I did not meant to shout, I simply copied/paste the *Title* of that article :) the link is usful IMO for those who want to help but don't have the time or knowledge of how to import the activex media player. it certainly helped me to quickly import media player in Delphi.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I believe you are right. I will try to use the `OnPlayStateChange` event. but the usage of Timer as shown in the article seems a bit over-kill for this rather simple task.

Comment: @zig - AFAICS the example use the timer to update media play progress. To be notified of a state change you just need to code in the OnPlayStateChange event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for now.
IMO it is far from being elegant, but it seems to work.
The key point as @Sertac mentioned in the comments is that the media player is loading asynchronous:

> or when state changes to be wmppsPlaying. If loading is asynchronous,
>   playing may begin well after the click handler returns.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MP := TWindowsMediaPlayer.Create(Self);
  MP.Parent := Panel1;
  MP.Align := alClient;    
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFirstTimePlay := True;
  Timer1.Interval := 50;
  MP.OnPlayStateChange := MP_PlayStateChange;
  MP.controls.stop;
  MP.settings.autoStart := False;  
  MP.URL := 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';  
  MP.controls.play; // start playing
end;

procedure TForm1.MP_PlayStateChange(ASender: TObject; NewState: Integer);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := (NewState = wmppsPlaying) and FFirstTimePlay;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  if FFirstTimePlay and MP.controls.isAvailable['currentPosition'] then
  begin
    FFirstTimePlay := False;
    MP.controls.currentPosition := 2;
    MP.controls.pause;
  end;
end;
```

This code will go to the position at 2 second and pause.
Now the user can press play to continue playing the rest of the video...
There is a small visual side effect that the video is "jumping" from an initial (zero) location to the X position.

Again, IMO this is far from being elegant, but maybe this is the only way.

Comment: Why do you need the timer, can't you just "pause" in the PlayStateChange event?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Good question . It seems I can pause in `PlayStateChange` event, but calling  `MP.controls.currentPosition := 2;` before/after Pause has no effect there. which is strange because `MP.controls.isAvailable['currentPosition']` returns `True`. So I was only able to pause and go to a location using a Timer :/